# eclipse plug-in development in java: how to run a run configuration from another running one?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi, bundle, run-configuration

I have created two views for eclipse. Each of this views is launched using a different run configuration (meaning a different one for each view).

What I want to do:

In the first view I have a list of elements. When I double click one element I want to start the other view (maybe from its run configuration) and only then to start all the bundles.

Any clue of how to do this?

Besides, I would like to send some parameters from the first view to the second one when launching.

I hope anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse run configuration is list of complex settings including Main class, VM arguments, JRE paths, and Classpath. The Eclipse view, in your words, is the perspective which contains various window panes; I think that's what you mean. The 2 concepts of run configuration and perspective/view are separate implementations of Eclipse, and not related.
So…what you’re asking seems impossible for Eclipse to do and not fitting to its design.

I propose you include your source folders into the Package Explorer workspace, which is basically just a file system. Afterwards, open/close the project folder when you want to change the views, using your words. I myself switch between 2 rather different projects between pure Java and Swing, and both contain their own Main function, for testing code in StackOverflow. I think this is similar to your goal.

I am not sure what you meant by “list of elements” in Eclipse. And I may not understand your exact problem.